# networkx graph measures considering node size

Tags: python, networkx, complex-networks

I have a directed graph instance i've created using networkx.

I want to calculate different metrics of the graph and the nodes of the graph (density, betweenness centrality, etc.).

The nodes in the graph have a size attribute. I wonder if there is some metric that consider the size of the node?

Thanks